# IEEEtran setting for 10-point type, 12-point vertical spacing

Tags: vertical-alignment, fontsize, ieeetran, journal-publishing

I am going to submit a journal paper that requires the following page formating:

- 14 double column, 12 pt pages
- double column page is defined as a 7.875" x 10.75" page with 10-point type, 12-point vertical spacing

Does it mean that I have to use `\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}` **or** I have to use `\documentclass[12pt,journal]{IEEEtran}` ?

Sorry, I have got confused here...

Comment: if it is a IEEE journal then you don't need to do anything.

Comment: "10-point type, 12-point vertical spacing" corresponds to a document class of `10pt`. I must confess I don't understand the expression "14 double column, 12 pt pages".

Comment: @percusse why ? They don't take PDF file ?

Comment: for review doesn't matter. For publication they fix your article themselves

Comment: @micro can you post your answer below ?

Comment: @Mico an answer maybe?

Comment: @percusse - Done. (I hadn't seen the OP's earlier comment until just now, as it was addressed to "micro"...)

Answer (score 1):

"10-point type, 12-point vertical spacing" may be achieved by passing the option `10pt` to the `\documentclass` instruction. For the specific document class of interest, you'd write:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}
```

I must confess I don't fully understand the expression "14 double column, 12 pt pages".